# How to change entity class names Doctrine generated

Tags: php, codeigniter, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I'm using Doctrine 2 and use these functions to generate entities from existing DB:

```
    $cmf = new DisconnectedClassMetadataFactory();
    $cmf->setEntityManager($this->em);
    $metadata = $cmf->getAllMetadata();
    $generator = new EntityGenerator();

    $generator->setUpdateEntityIfExists(true);
    $generator->setGenerateStubMethods(true);
    $generator->setGenerateAnnotations(true);
    $generator->generate($metadata, APPPATH."models/entities");
```

but i want to change names of entity class just like these: "ActionsEntity", "UserEntity". Not want "Actions" and "User" etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to ORM/Tools/EntityGenerator.php Line 347

```
private function _generateEntityClassName(ClassMetadataInfo $metadata)
```

apply changes you want in this function.

Go to Line 584

```
private function _generateEntityStubMethods(ClassMetadataInfo $metadata)
```

apply changes you want in this function.

Go to Line 766

```
private function _generateAssociationMappingPropertyDocBlock
```

apply changes you want in this function.